# TreeMap doesn't sort

Tags: java, treemap

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Doctor d = (Doctor)o;
    return (doctor_name.compareTo(d.doctor_name));
}
```

This is my comparable in Doctor class

```
jTextArea.setText("");
int doctor_id = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
String doctor_name = jTextField3.getText();
String hospitalName = jTextField4.getText();

Doctor d = new Doctor(doctor_id,doctor_name,hospitalName);
hmDoctor.put(doctor_id, d);
```

This is my hashmap

and this is my tree map

```
TreeMap<Integer,Doctor> tmDoctor = new TreMap<Integer,Doctor>(hmDoctor);
jTextArea.setText("");
Set keys = tmDoctor.keySet();
Iterator<Integer> ite = keys.iterator();

while(ite.hasNext())
{
    int doctorID = ite.next();
    Doctor d = tmDoctor.get(doctorID);
    tmDoctor.put(doctorID, d);
    jTextArea1.append(d.toString());
}
```

It doesn't sort doctor names. Why?

Answer (score 10):

The `TreeMap` sorts elements according to their keys, not values.
As an alternative, you could use a `TreeMap<String, Doctor>` indexed by the doctor's name.
Or, depending on what you need to do, you can just keep the doctors in a `TreeSet`.

Comment: i can do that with tree set by doctorName isnt it ?

Comment: If you were to go with a set, it would  be a sorted collection of doctors (you'd probably have to override `equals()` as well), which would allow tests such as `yourSet.contains(d)`. If you go with the map by name, you could do `yourMap.get("Gregory House")` to get the `Doctor` object.

Comment: private TreeMap<String, Doctor> tmDoctor = new TreeMap<String,Doctor>(); if i do that and it works now but whats the meaning of Comparable in Doctor class ?

Comment: The fact that `Doctor` implements `Comparable` would allow it to to appear in a `TreeSet<Doctor>` or a `TreeMap<Doctor,...>` i.e. serve as a key for the tree rather than a value. It would also mean that you could use `Arrays.sort()` on a `Doctor[]`.